# Reload part of image in TKinter canvas (i.e. erasing)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to make a mask on top of an image and for that I made an editor in TKinter that opens an image and allows me to draw on top of it. Unfortunately I have no idea how to implement an "Erase" function.

In the code below I create an example image which I then load with the editor. I can now draw over it in blue by pressing the Left Mouse Button. To erase I want to use the Right Mouse Button. Right now I just simply draw in red to show where I want to erase. In the end I would like to "reload" the image where I now have the red so that it removes the blue that I added.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class ImgEditor(object):

    def __init__(self,FileImg):
        self.root = tk.Tk()        

        #Picture
        self.Img = Image.open(FileImg)
        self.Imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.Img)

        #Canvas
        self.Cv = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=800 , height=600)
        self.Cv.grid(row=0, column=0)

        #Set-up
        self.Drawing=False
        self.Erasing=False
        self.xold=None
        self.yold=None
        self.line_width = 40
        self.Color="#ff0000"

        # Mouse Actions (Left Click = Draw, Right Click = Erase)
        self.Cv.bind("<Motion>", self.Motion)
        self.Cv.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.B1Down)
        self.Cv.bind("<ButtonPress-3>", self.B3Down)
        self.Cv.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.BUp)
        self.Cv.bind("<ButtonRelease-3>", self.BUp)

        # Fit Image
        self.ImRes = self.Img.size
        self.Scale = min(min(800/self.ImRes[0],600/self.ImRes[1]),1.0)
        self.Imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.Img.resize((int(self.ImRes[0]*self.Scale),int(self.ImRes[1]*self.Scale)),Image.LANCZOS))
        self.Cv.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=self.Imgtk)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def B1Down(self,event): #Draw
        self.xold=event.x
        self.yold=event.y
        self.Color="#0000ff"
        self.Drawing=True
        self.Erasing=False
        self.Draw(self.xold,self.yold,self.xold,self.yold)

    def B3Down(self,event): #Erase
        self.xold=event.x
        self.yold=event.y
        self.Color="#ff0000"
        self.Drawing=False
        self.Erasing=True
        self.Draw(self.xold,self.yold,self.xold,self.yold)

    def BUp(self,event):
        self.Drawing=False
        self.Erasing=False

    def Draw(self,xo,yo,xn,yn):
        self.Cv.create_line(xo,yo,xn,yn,width=self.line_width,fill=self.Color,capstyle=tk.ROUND, smooth=tk.TRUE)

    def Motion(self,event):
        if self.Drawing or self.Erasing:
            xo=self.xold
            yo=self.yold
            xn=event.x
            yn=event.y
            self.Draw(xo,yo,xn,yn)
            self.xold=xn
            self.yold=yn


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Example Image
    sx,sy=600,800
    MBase=np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: 255/2*(i/sx + (j/sy)**2), (sx, sy), dtype=float)
    Image.fromarray(np.uint8(MBase),mode="L").save("Test.png","png")   
    # Main Editor
    ge=ImgEditor("Test.png")
```

Comment: You don't need to "reload" the underlying image, it's still there in its entirety.  What you need to do is delete some of the line objects you drew on top of it.  The canvas `.find_overlapping()` or similar methods could be used to identify the lines to delete.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the suggestion. If no one comes up with a working solution I'll try it! PS: Would you happen to know if it is possible to have the lines have a semi transparent fill?

Comment: Tkinter doesn't really support transparency.  I think the closest you could get would be a stipple pattern (something like a checkerboard pattern of fully opaque and fully transparent pixels).  This generally looks awful on thin lines.